# Finding the transition matrix of a recurrence relation

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, transition-matrix

Consider the following recurrence relation :
$$X_{k+4} = X_{k+3} + X_{k+1} - X_k$$
$1)$ Find the transition matrix $A$ corresponding to the recurrence relation.

$2)$ Show that $A$ is not diagonalizable.

---

The transition matrix $A$ that I found was:
\begin{pmatrix}
     0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
However, I can't easily find the eigenvalues of $A$. Therefore, I think that the $A$ that I got is wrong. Could someone explain how to properly get the $A$ matrix?

Comment: hope it helps. http://www.bluebit.gr/matrix-calculator/calculate.aspx     $$rank=4\\det=1\\eigenvalues 1,1,\frac 12 \pm \sqrt 3$$

Comment: I forgot $\frac 12$ before $\sqrt 3$

Answer (score 1):

With a look to equation : the characteristic equation for eigen values is : $$r^4=r^3+r-1\\
r^4-r^3-(r-1)=0\\(r-1)(r^3-1)=0\\r=1,1,r^2+r-1=0 \to r=\frac 12 \pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt 3$$

Answer (score 0):

Define $z_k$ to be the vector
$$
z_k = \pmatrix{z_k^1\\z_{k}^2\\z_k^3\\z_k^4}
= \pmatrix{x_{k}\\x_{k+1}\\x_{k+2}\\x_{k+3}} 
$$
(note: the superscripts are not exponents).
We can express your recurrence relation as the following system of first-order relations:
$$
\begin{cases}z_{k+1}^1 = z_k^2\\
z_{k+1}^2 = z_k^3\\
z_{k+1}^3 = z_k^4\\
z_{k+1}^4 = - z_k^1 + z_k^2 + z_k^4 
\end{cases} \implies
z_{k+1} = \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    -1&1&0&1 } z_k.
$$
Your matrix was correct! You should compute the characteristic polynomial of the matrix to be 
$$
p(x) = x^4 - x^3 - x + 1 = (x-1)^2(x^2 + x + 1).
$$
In order to show that the matrix fails to be diagonalizable, it suffices to check that $M - I$ has a nullspace of dimension $1$, even though the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ has algebraic multiplicity $2$.

Comment: If this is correct, then the matrix *is* diagonalizable, isn't it?

Comment: @saulspatz depends on the definition of "diagonalizable".  In some contexts, diagonalizable specifically means "diagonalizable with real eigenvalues" (i.e. similar to a real diagonal matrix).

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that.

Comment: @saulspatz that being said, it looks like I did have a mistake.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Could you be a bit more specific regarding "In order to show that the matrix fails to be diagonalizable..."?